# How can I delete numbered files in a given range?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have `folderA` that has some files with a number sequence starting with `a_000000`. What I want to do is to delete files starting from a specific number: let's say `a_000750` till the end of files in this `folderA`. Could anyone please advise how to do this using shell script?

Comment: Can I assume that all of those filenames have 6-digit suffixes?

Comment: yes they are :) they start from a_000000 till some number

Comment: `rm a_000[89]* a_0007[5-9]*` ?

Comment: @Rinzwind could you please explain this command?

Comment: It is a remove with wildcards... nothing more?

Comment: @Rinzwind so in your commend it will delete which files with which numbers?

Comment: It would include `a_000750` as well (can be corrected with one more term, I suppose).

Comment: @muru could you explain Rinzwind's comment. As it seems very easy but I don't understand it :)

Comment: @user1460166 `a_000[89]*` includes every file beginning with `a_0008` or `a_0009`, and `a_0007[5-9]*` includes every file beginning with `a_0007` and then containing a number between 5 and 9, followed by anything.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming you know or can guess the end of the range, you could use [brace expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace):

```
rm a_{000750..000850}
```

The above will delete the 101 files between a_000750 and a_000850 inclusive (and complain about filenames that refer to non-existing files). If you have too many files for that, use `find`:

```
find . -name 'a_*' | while read -r file; do 
  [ "${file#./a_}" -gt 000749 ] && rm -v "$file" 
done
```

Here, the `find` simply lists all files matching `a_*`. The list is passed to a `while` loop where each file name is read into the variable `$file`. Then, using bash's [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) features, if the numerical part (find prints files as `./file`, so `${file#./a_}` prints the number only) is `000750` or greater, the file is deleted. The `-v` is just there so you can see what files were removed.

Note that the above assumes sane file names. If your names can have spaces, newlines or other weird characters, use this instead:

```
find . -name 'a_*' -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' file; do 
  [ "${file#./a_}" -gt 000749 ] && rm -v "$file" 
done
```

Comment: Why avoid `[[`?

Comment: @muru why use it? `[[` doesn't simplify things here `[[ "${file#./a_}" > 000749 ]]` for example, doesn't even make it any shorter. I don't like using unnecessary syntax and this one will even work in simpler shells like `dash`.

Comment: Because `[[` handles spaces and weirdnesses better (i don't care much for `>` either).

Comment: @muru yes, but `[` is fine if you quote the variable as I have, works on far more shells and is simpler.

Comment: If you insist. Not my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex './a_[0-9]{6}' -execdir bash -c '[[ ${1##./a_} > 000750 ]] && echo $1' "removing: " {} \;
```

Or:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex './a_[0-9]{6}' | sort | sed '0,/000750/d' | xargs echo
```

The first method assumes a fixed prefix, strips it off and checks the value.

The second method assumes a fixed-length suffix (and a common fixed prefix) and relies on that fact; and that, while `201` comes before `31` in lexicographically, it doesn't before `031`.

Test this out with the `echo` command, and once you're sure it lists the correct files, use `rm` instead.

Comment: none of them is working :/

Comment: @user1460166 ah, that's probably due the regex matching. I'll update it.

Comment: still not working. btw, the files are .png :)

Comment: @user1460166 can you say how it is not working?

Comment: I open the terminal, cd to the folder then copy your line and paste it, but the files are not deleted

Comment: @user1460166 the commands don't delete, as i have stated. Read the last line again.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash you can run:

```
for i in {1001..3000} ; do rm file_"$i".dat ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

## POSIX shell solution

[terdon's first solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/529283/295286)  relies on brace expansion, which is a property of `bash` and `ksh`, however it cannot be used in the standard `/bin/sh` shell, which on Ubuntu is symlinked to `/bin/dash`.

In cases where you have to rely `/bin/sh` for portability of your scripts, there's generally two ways to approach this. One would be via globbing. Just `cd folderA` and from there run `rm a_*`. The other way, would be to implement a C-style for loop alternative using `while <CONDITION>;do ...done` in shell language and format the numbers with `printf`:

```
$ sh -c 'i=0;while [ $i -le 750 ]; do filename=$(printf "a_%06d" $i);echo "$filename";i=$((i+1)) ;done'
```

Notice that here I use `echo`. Replace `echo "$filename"` with `rm ./"$filename"` or `rm -- "$filename"` when you're ready to delete the files. Also note, that this should be performed when you already `cd`ed into the desired directory.

## (ab)using awk

Awk being a nice C-like language can help us in two ways: (1) we can generate filenames with for-loop and format them via `sprintf` function, and (2) delete said files via `system()` command, which will pass our generated filename and `rm` command to `/bin/sh` :

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<=750;i++){filename=sprintf("a_%06d",i);system("rm "filename);} }'
```

## Perl

Continuing with the idea of portable approach where we "generate" filenames, we can do same in Perl:

```
perl -le 'for(0..750){$fd=sprintf("a_%06d",$_);unlink($fd)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as**

```
rm partialfilename* -f
```

In your example it is

```
rm a_00075* -f
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but that's not a range, those are all files starting with `a_00075`...

Comment: * is a wildcard, OP is looking for an answer on how to delete a RANGE of things... eg if you had files 1 through 100, and wanted to delete #41 to #75