# Command Line regextype to delete files

Tags: command-line

I have a series of files that always start with at least 5 numerical values like:

85966_88.jpg

[Using this answer I learned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529270/how-can-i-delete-numbered-files-in-a-given-range) to use the find and regextype in a command to delete files like this:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex './a_[0-9]{6}' -execdir bash -c '[[ ${1##./a_} > 000750 ]] && echo $1' "removing: " {} \;
```

I altered this command to suite my needs like this:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex './[0-9]{5}' -execdir bash -c '[[ ${1##./} > 000001 ]] && echo $1' "removing: " {} \;
```

I execute the command and it does not delete the files. I cannot figure out how to remove all .jpg that have numeric values in the first 5 digits and then _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the command *as written* doesn't delete anything: as noted in the a nswer you linked

> Test this out with the `echo` command, and once you're sure it lists the correct files, use `rm` instead.

Second, it's over-complicated for your case, since you don't want to limit the removal to a range or subset of the matches (so you don't need the shell test stuff) - you could simply do

```
find -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[0-9]{5}_.*\.jpg' -print
```

(to test) and replace `-print` by `-delete` once you're satisfied it's working right.

However even regex seems overcomplicated - a simple glob match is actually less typing:

```
find -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*.jpg' -print
```

(again, replace `-print` by `-delete` when you're sure).

If you don't need to search recursively, a simple shell glob should work:

```
rm -i [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*.jpg
```

Comment: I strongly suggest considering using the command `trash` from the package `trash-cli` instead of `-delete` or `rm` when using anything like regex or wildcards.  Partially just to entrench it as a habit. Too darn easy to make a tragic mistake the other way. Steeldriver, please correct me if I'm wrong in assuming delete is a sort of faster rm built in to find. I can't find it in man find. Maybe your version is newer. My findutils is 4.6.0+git+20160126-2.